# How to Implement SwiftUI to Pull Refresh to Get New Network Data？

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, pull-to-refresh

I want to add drop-down refresh, but I'm not sure which method is the best.

```swift
//DataModel
    struct Post: Codable, Hashable,Identifiable {
        let id: Int
        let username: String
        let body: String
    }

     class Service {
            static let shared = Service()
            enter code here
            func fetchPosts(completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> ()) {
                guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:1337/post") else {
                    fatalError("URL is not correct!")
                }
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
                    let posts = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(posts)
                    }
                }.resume()
            }
        }

        struct Find: View {

            @State var model = PostListViewModel()

            var body: some View {
                List {
                    ForEach(model.posts) { post in
                        Text(post.username)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: final class PostListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        fetchPosts()
    }
    
    var posts = [Post]() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchPosts() {
        Service().fetchPosts {
            self.posts = $0
        }
    }
    
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<PostListViewModel,Never>()
}

Comment: ObservableObjects use objectWillChange in willSet.